# Take out punctuation within a word

Tags: python

I have a function that takes as parameters a punctuation symbol and a list of words. The function looks in each word and splits up the punctuation. For example:

```
["I...love", "you"] ---> ["I","love","you"]
```

The only problem is that I am using a so-called "incomprehensible list comprehension" to do it, and it is exhibiting some strange behaviour:

```
def take_out(symbol, word_list):
        for word in word_list:
            if symbol in word and "http" not in word :
                word_list[word_list.index(word)] = (" ".join([x for x in word.split(symbol)])).split()
        word_list = [[item] if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in word_list]
        word_list = [item for sublist in word_list for item in sublist]
        return word_list
```

Can anyone suggest another way of accomplishing this task without using a nebulous approach as I have.

Comment: Why don't you write some code that you *do* understand?

Comment: Whenever you don't understand a list comprehension, write it out with loops and conditions and debug it there. If you want to put it back together as a list comprehension later then you can always worry about the syntax then.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I DO understand what I have written, but I do not like it's complexity. I have posted this question to see if there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: try to split the function into smaller functions where each has a smaller task to perform e.g., `http` check, `isinstance()` check -- it is a job for other functions. Limit `take_out()` to a single task only: split items with the given punctuation symbol into several words and replace them: `def take_out(symbol, words): return [no_punct_word for w in words for no_punct_word in w.split(symbol)]`

Comment: So what does *"strange behaviour"* mean? If it's working but you think it could be improved, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, try this:

```
z = []
for i in ["I...love","you"]:
    for j in i.split("..."):
        z.append(j)
print(z)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks DJK, with my edit it works perfectly. All I was seeking was a simpler way to accomplish this task, this seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can see what your code does inserting a couple of print lines. It will help you to understand it.

> ```
> def take_out(symbol, word_list):
>   for word in word_list:
>     if symbol in word and "http" not in word :
>       word_list[word_list.index(word)] = (" ".join([x for x in word.split(symbol)])).split()
>       print(word_list)
>   word_list = [[item] if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in word_list]
>   print(word_list)
>   word_list = [item for sublist in word_list for item in sublist]
>   print(word_list)
>   return word_list
> ```

And here is the output:

> ```
> >>> take_out('.', ['I...love','you','...or not?'],)
>   [['I', 'love'], 'you', '...or not?']
>   [['I', 'love'], 'you', ['or', 'not?']]
>   [['I', 'love'], ['you'], ['or', 'not?']]
>   ['I', 'love', 'you', 'or', 'not?']
> ```

Your code is first splitting each element of the list and putting the result in place of the original. Thus, for the list: ['I...love','you','...or not?'], it gets its first member 'I...love', splits it and the result is a list of words ['I','love']. Places the result in place of the original [['I','love'],'you','...or not?]. Continues with the second element. There is nothing to split so it moves to the third one and splits it. Exits the loop.

The word list now looks like [['I','love'],'you',['or','not?]]. The first list comprehension is used to normalize all the elements in the list. item or [item] Do you understand it now?. item if is already a list or [item] if is a string. Thus, 'you' becomes ['you'].

The previous normalization is needed for the last list comprehension to work. What it does is to take every item from the inner lists and put them in a list. So [['I','love'],['you'],['or','not?']] becomes ['I','love','you','or','not?']. I hope this helps you to better understand your code.